# How can I update a value in a table using a join clause in the update?

Tags: sql-server

I have two tables:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Answer] (
    [AnswerId]    INT              IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [Number]      INT              NOT NULL,
    [QuestionId]  INT              NOT NULL,
    [QuestionUId] UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NULL
);

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Question] (
    [QuestionId]       INT              IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL, 
    [QuestionUId]      UNIQUEIDENTIFIER DEFAULT (newid()) NOT NULL
);
```

The `QuestionUId` field in the Answer table is currently empty. The QuestionId field in the Answer table is populated with entries.

How can I update this field with the QuestionUId value from the Question table. I am guessing that I need an update that somehow has a join in it. Can someone suggest how I could do this so I can 
try it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try:

```
update answer
set questionUId = q.quesitonUId
from answer a
inner join question q on a.questionId = q.questionId
```